# Appending row content to another row in the html table

Tags: html, dom, html-table

In HTML doc, I am trying to combine two rows contents into one row in HTML table. After combining the row, **dom has to be updated** with this new row and the previous two are to be removed.
For example: Suppose the table look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected result should have one row in the document.

```
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is providing the solution

```
  function copyDiv(){
  var firstRow= document.querySelector("tr:nth-child(1)");
  var secondRow = document.querySelector("tr:nth-child(2)");
  firstRow.innerHTML += secondRow.innerHTML;
  document.querySelector("table").deleteRow("1");
     }
```